# Wordpress: Requested URL was not found

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I have wordpress installed and I'm getting this permalink error:

> The requested URL /hello-world/ was not found on this server.

This is my .htaccess in the root folder:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php?$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and this is my apache2 config file:

```
<VirtualHost *>

        ServerName x.ay.com
        ServerAlias www.x.y.com
        ServerAdmin x@y.ch
        DocumentRoot /var/www/x/public_html
        <Directory /var/www/x/public_html>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.x.y.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =x.y.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

So what's wrong? I kind of think, that changes to my .htaccess are ignored?
But what I figured out. I'm being redirected to the index homepage with an "/?/" in the URL:

```
https://x.y.com/?/hello-world/
```

Where is the problem? May it be the Rewrite in the apache2 config file (where I already rewrite, to ensure that everything is redirected to https?).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try to run this on the server "a2enmod rewrite" ?

Comment: @ezOSC Yes. It's "already enabled". Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Test your site!

Comment: In comment, the OP said he already try it

Comment: sorry i'm not yet read